# How to speed up the receipt of contacts from android phone?

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I write code for getting contacts from phone book, but he works very slow, how i think.
For example in samsung galaxy s8 for 189 phone numbers (each contact may have more than one number) average speed is 4582ms. 5 seconds! it's very slow how i think.

I cut out part of the code that is responsible for the calculation of time and parsing to check for correctness, the speed is not affected much:

```
class ContactLoader(private val context: Context) {

    fun getContactList(): List<ContactEntity> {
        val result = mutableListOf<ContactEntity>()
        val contentResolver = context.contentResolver

        val cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null)

        if (cursor != null && cursor.count > 0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                val id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID))
                val name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME))

                if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)) > 0) {
                    val secondCursor = contentResolver.query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                            arrayOf(id),
                            null
                    )

                    while (secondCursor.moveToNext()) {
                        val phone = secondCursor.getString(secondCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER))

                        val contactEntity = ContactEntity(
                                userId = id,
                                userName = name,
                                phone = phone,
                                phoneHash = hashUtils.fromNumberToHash(phone.replace("""\D""".toRegex(), ""))
                        )
                        result.add(contactEntity)
                    }

                    secondCursor.close()
                }
            }
        }

        cursor?.close()

        return result
    }
}
```

How to speed up getting contact from phone?

Answer (score 0):

- Try adding a projection to your cursor ... The req columns.
- Try executing the above fuction using a background thread and update the list using a UI  thread.
- Try having the selection criteria which you have  mentioned in your second cursor , in your first cursor itself .. avoid using the nested statement .. which can be made into a single entity.
  This might improve to some extent.